# Write a random function without using stl functions

Tags: c++

I need a function which can generate random numbers without using the standard library functions. I thought `time()%100` would be good but when you run in a loop, say 10 times, you get the same value all the time. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is this homework? Retagging would be in order if it is.

Comment: "Is there a better way..." Always.

Comment: How about [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/), its is not part of STL.

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: wikipedia [gives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) a very simple algorihm that you could implement. Use e.g. time() to initialize it.

Comment: Your teacher really assigned something like this, without hinting at an algorithm? I can't tell whether that's really good or really bad...

Answer (score 4):

The simplest classical generator is the linear congruent generator.  The
choice of parameters for it is critical, however; see *Random Number
Generators: Good Ones Are Hard to Find* (Park and Miller, CACM Oct.,
1988).  Something like:

```
static int current;         //  Set to arbitrary value by seed
static long long const a = 48271;
static long long const m = 2147483647; 

int
rand()
{
    current = (a * current) % m;
    return current;
}
```

(This assumes at least 32 bit int's.)

Answer (score 2):

Just implement a simple [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG), using e.g. the [Linear Congruential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) method - it's only a couple of lines of code.